# Resource file missing from JAR after gradle build

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot

I have a resource file call names.txt that is called by my code when I hit a rest endpoint.

This is held in  src//main//resources//names.txt. I have an application.yml that references the file location as such

```
file:
    namesPath: src//main//resources//names.txt
```

when I build and run my solution everything works fine. If i run the jar from the commandline outside the IDE it also works fine.

How ever if I copy that JAR to another instance, it complains and says that it cannot find the file referenced

If I browse the JAR the file is there but it is under BOOT-INF/Classes/names.txt

How do I solve this so I can deploy the JAR wherever I want?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say what is wrong without seeing your build.gradle file but I would expect if you put something like below in your build file the resource files should end up in the right location:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/gen/java']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = [src/main/resources']
        }
    }
    ....
}
```